# MRTK - Get state of Interactible object

Tags: unity-game-engine, mrtk

I am trying to get objects with a certain state. I set a tag to objects I want to check and I wrote a code something like this:

```
GameObject[] objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("GraphNode");
foreach (GameObject obj in objects) {
    Debug.Log(obj.GetComponent<Interactable>().GetStateValue(InteractableStates.InteractableStateEnum.Pressed));
}
```

Although, this is not working. Even when the object is pressed or focused, the Log returns `0`. The objects I am checking are elements with component `Interactable` and they are set to `Toggle` selection mode. I set them target themes so I would see whether they are pressed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`DimensionIndex` was what I was looking for. If the `Interactable` is set to Toggle, clicking on it or "performing given action" will alternate the dimension index to 0 or 1. So getting "clicked" or selected objects is as easy as:

```
foreach (GameObject graphNode in graphNodes)
{
    Debug.Log(graphNode.GetComponent<Interactable>().CurrentDimension);
}
```

Whereas the object returning "1" is clicked.